# Cacluate the sum/avg of an attribute in Apache pig

Tags: apache-pig

How can I calculate the avg or sum of an attribute in Apache pig (vertically not horizontally). Lots of example are available for doing this horizontally but not  vertically.

This is my code

```
f1 = LOAD '/user/maria_dev/flightdelays/flight_delays1.csv' USING 
 PigStorage(',') AS (Year:int,  ArrDelay:chararray);

f123 =  f1;
ff123 = FILTER f123 BY something;
grp = GROUP ff123 ALL;
cnt = FOREACH grp GENERATE COUNT(ff123);-- this counts the number of rows and works fine
DUMP cnt;

-- The below code is the problem
DESCRIBE grp;
cntsum = FOREACH grp GENERATE FLATTEN(ff123.ArrDelay);
DESCRIBE cntsum;
```

and the output:

```
(2008,30)
(2009,60)
(2)
 grp: {group: chararray,ff123: {(Year: int,ArrDelay: chararray)}}
cntsum: {null::ArrDelay: chararray}
```

But this throw me an error:

```
cntsum = FOREACH grp GENERATE SUM((int)FLATTEN(ff123.ArrDelay));
DESCRIBE cntsum;
```

I need to get 90 as output (30+60)

By the way, what is this schema as the output:

```
 cntsum: {null::ArrDelay: chararray}
```

using pig Apache Pig version 0.16.0.2.6.5.0-292

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should load ArrDelay as int column

```
f1 = LOAD '/user/maria_dev/flightdelays/flight_delays1.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS (Year:int,  ArrDelay:int);
ff123 = FILTER f1 BY something;
grp = GROUP ff123 ALL;
total = FOREACH grp GENERATE SUM(ff123.ArrDelay);
DUMP total;
```

If that is not an option then load ArrDelay into chararray and then cast it before the group all and sum

```
f1 = LOAD '/user/maria_dev/flightdelays/flight_delays1.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS (Year:int,  ArrDelay:chararray);
ff123 = FILTER f1 BY something;
f2 = FOREACH ff123 GENERATE Year, (int)ArrDelay as ArrDelay;
grp = GROUP f2 ALL;
total = FOREACH grp GENERATE SUM(f2.ArrDelay);
DUMP total;
```

Comment: Sweet, worked fine, thx, two questions please, 1: Why should this casting done before the SUM function? 2: Can you please explain about this schema cntsum: {null::ArrDelay: chararray} too,